# Tap working only at the end of the scroll movement in ScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

My project deals with Xcode IOS 10+ for iPhone, language is Objective C.

I have created a ScrollView including a content view. Within the content view there is one UIImageView associated with a TapGestureRecognizer. All of these have been made visually with the StoryBoard.

The TapGestureRecognizers are working, as long as the scroll movement has ended. Otherwise if the user scrolls, it is not possible to tap.

UserInterraction flag is enabled, Delays Content Touches flag has been set to false. Yet it is not working.

Any of you would have met similar issues and how would you fixed it?

Comment: What about `gestureRecognizer:shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the scroll view will consume the tap gesture when it is scrolling since it is used to stop the scroll movement. Try setting a delegate on your UITapGestureRecognizer and respond to the delegate method shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    // Possibly check for your two gesture recognizer here
    return YES;
}
```